# Pandas - Grouping rows and averaging per column

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe with the structure below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id': [0,0,0,1,1,1],
               'x': [2,3,4,3,4,5],
               'y': [5,6,7,2,2,5],
               'z': [8,8,2,2,6,7]})
```

How to group data based on group_id values and calculate averages by `group_id` of columns `x`, `y`, `z`?

Expected output:

```
group_id | x | y | z
  0      | 3 | 6 | 6
  1      | 4 | 3 | 5
```

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['group_id']).mean()`

Comment: Easier than I thought